# In SSAS, can parent-child DATAMEMBER name be customised

Tags: ssas, mdx

In a parent-child dimension in SSAS, the datamember is automatically named the same as the parent.

E.g.

- Division X Risk Register

  - **Division X Risk Register**
  - Department A Risk Register
  - Department B Risk Register
- Division Y Risk Register

  - **Division Y Risk Register**
  - Department P Risk Register
  - Department Q Risk Register

I want all the datamembers to be named "Executive Risk Register", as follows:

- Division X Risk Register

  - **Executive Risk Register**
  - Department A Risk Register
  - Department B Risk Register
- Division Y Risk Register

  - **Executive Risk Register**
  - Department P Risk Register
  - Department Q Risk Register

(b.t.w. if the the children also have children, their datamembers must also be "Executive Risk Register").

Can this be done by setting something on the dimension in SSAS or do I have to handle it separately in every MDX query?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Changing the MembersWithDataCaption property in the Parent attribute to "Executive Risk Register"?